# There is a way to syntax highlight GraphQl TypeDef inside ` ` (grave accent) in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, graphql

I Want to syntax highlight the code inside typeDef. It is possible?

There is a extension for this? Or I have to code the typeDef other way?

```
export const typeDef = `
 type User {
  _id: ID!
  email: String!
  password: String
  createdEvents: [Event!]
 }

 type AuthData {
  userId: ID!
  token: String!
  tokenExpiration: Int!
 }

 input UserInput {
  email: String!
  password: String!
 }
`;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using the [right extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Prisma.vscode-graphql), you need to use the `gql` tag from `graphql-tag`.

```
const gql = require('graphql-tag')

const typeDefs = gql`
  type User { ... }
`
```

The tag parses the provided string and returns a `DocumentNode` object, which is what should be passed to `makeExecutableSchema` or the `ApolloServer` constructor. On the client side, the queries used by ApolloClient are also expected to be `DocumentNode` objects and should be wrapped the same way.

The extension is able to detect usage of the tag and apply syntax highlighting accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I need. I have this extension, but I not reconfigured correctly .

Comment: @DaniloCunha You can also use a hack `const gql = String.raw` to get syntax highlighting without needing to download `graphql-tag` or similar packages → https://stackoverflow.com/a/67135985/6141587

Comment: export const gql = String.raw didn't work for me when I tried to run my server. But when I turned off the "export" it did. require("graphql-tag") also works too.

Answer (score 16):

Use [String.raw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) to trick VSCode into Syntax Highlighting GraphQL. It works for other languages as well.

```
export const gql = String.raw

export const typeDef = gql`
  type User {
    _id: ID!
    email: String!
    password: String
    createdEvents: [Event!]
  }

  type AuthData {
    userId: ID!
    token: String!
    tokenExpiration: Int!
  }

  input UserInput {
    email: String!
    password: String!
  }
`
```

Comment: This is just awesome.