# GraphQL syntax highlighting in VSCode js file

Tags: visual-studio-code, graphql

Been looking for this type or extension or setting.
Is there any?

Answer (score 9):

I was looking something similar myself and found this:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GraphQL.vscode-graphql

It has syntax highlighting, validation and more:

> GraphQL extension for VSCode adds syntax highlighting, validation,
> and language features like go to definition, hover information and
> autocompletion for graphql projects. This extension also works with
> queries annotated with gql tag.

Comment: You can also use a hack `const gql = String.raw` to get syntax highlighting without needing to download `graphql-tag` or similar packages → https://stackoverflow.com/a/67135985/6141587