# How to change texts color inside Diacritical mark?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am following a tutorial on YouTube. But when I code inside of a diacritical mark, the color of my text is different from the tutorials and it does not suggest like the tutorial, but it still works. How do I  fix it?

This is my code:

[image]

This is what it looks like in the tutorial:

[image]

Comment: It may depend on the language being used.  Is this a brand new file? Have you configured the file to be using the correct language?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? [There is a way to syntax highlight GraphQl TypeDef inside ` ` (grave accent) in vscode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60643685/there-is-a-way-to-syntax-highlight-graphql-typedef-inside-grave-accent-in/67135985#67135985)

Comment: You should tag and mention the language you are using.

Comment: sorry about this, i'm using javascript.